# How to Redirect .NET Web Site to WordPress Site Seamlessly using Single Sign-On

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm working on a .NET web site that authenticates via usernames/passwords stored in a database. We have a separate site running on WordPress for documentation and FAQs. It needs to be protected from unauthorized users as well, but we want a single-sign-on solution. A link on the main site will take them to the WordPress site without the need to login again or to have separate username/logins for the WordPress site. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I would think OAuth could help you with this. Although i'm not sure on the exact mechanics between .NET => passing OAuth Tokens => WordPress 

You might also be able to do this with a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) created on the .NET site - and authenticated on the WordPress site.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a plugin with little to no coding? Our team consists of .NET developers. None of us knows php.

Comment: This plugin looks promising [Simple JWT Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-jwt-login/) I did a quick search and saw a handful of JWT plugins. 

The plugin even claims "This plugin allows you to login or register to a WordPress website using a JWT." 

Which sounds like you would be able to seamlessly log your users into this wordpress, while also making them logins for the wordpress app. 

It claims:
`URL
Header
Cookie
Session` as the methods for login - so if you can generate URL's/JSWT from your .net app
 [search result](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/jwt/)

Comment: Thank you. Simple-JWT-Login worked well. I get a token with a username/password, then pass that token in the redirect to take the user to the site. 
However, we also want to lock down the site to anyone but registered users (and redirected users from our main site). We use the Force Login plugin for this, but as soon as I enable Force Login, the call to get the token returns a null token. Simple-JWT-Login seems to be incompatible with Force Login.

Comment: If you are using the tokens for page access, does it not check to make sure they are authenticated first? Might be some JWT logic you can add to do this removing the Force Login dependency.

Comment: Yes. I've asked our WordPress developer about options for adding code so we can remove one of the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicu, the author of Simple-JWT-Login, fixed the issue, so now that plug-in is compatible with Force Login. I receive a valid token and can redirect from our web site to our FAQ site even though the FAQ site is locked down with Force Login. Nico was responsive when I posted the problem. I highly recommend his plug-in. Easy to use and configure.